# Issues getting data from specific user (firestore rules)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hey i have an issue getting the data from a specific user. I have a collection of "Orders" in this collection i saved the userID of the user that created the Order. I can get all Orders but how do i get only the Orders from that user? And if i change the Firestore rules to :
`allow read, write: if resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;` im not getting any "orders" anymore.

I tried chaning the rules, i get the whole list when i check for authorised users. But still not for that specific one.

```js
export class BestellungService {
  pizza;
  order: Order;

  private ordersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Order>;
  private orders: Observable<Order[]>;


  constructor(private NavController: NavController,db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.ordersCollection = db.collection<Order>("Bestellungen");

    this.orders = this.ordersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        })
      })
    )


   }
 getOrders(){
    return this.orders;
  }

  getOrder(id){
    return this.ordersCollection.doc<Order>(id).valueChanges();
  }


  updateOrder(orders: Order, id: string){
    return this.ordersCollection.doc(id).update(orders);
  }

  addOrder(order: Order){
    //var pizzenList = order.pizzen.map((obj)=> {return Object.assign({}, obj)});
    const newOrder: Order ={
      userID: order.userID,
      status: order.status,
      pizzen: order.pizzen,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
      total: order.total,
      total_string: order.total_string,
      location: order.location
    }
    return this.ordersCollection.add(newOrder);
  }

  removeOrder(id){
    return this.ordersCollection.doc(id).delete();
  }
}
```

This is how i add/get orders.

```js
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  orders: Order[];
  userEmail: string;
  userID: string;
  subscription;
  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private authService: AuthenticateService,
    private BestellungService: BestellungService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("HomePage ngOnInit"); 

    if(this.authService.userDetails()){
      this.userEmail = this.authService.userDetails().email;
      this.userID = this.authService.userDetails().uid;
      let subscription = this.BestellungService.getOrders().subscribe(res=>{
        this.orders = res;
        console.log("RES: ",res);
        console.log("bestellungen: ",this.orders);
      });
      this.subscription = subscription;
    }else{
      this.navCtrl.navigateBack('');
    }


  }
}
```

this is how i get them to display

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Bestellungen/{bestellungID}{
    allow read, write: if resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
    //allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{userID}{
    allow read, write: if userID == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }

  function getUserData(){
  return get(/database/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
  }
}
```

These are the rules i expected to work. I tried the rules with the SImulator and i got the the permission but it doesnt work in my code.

My expected result is a list of Orders from the current logged in user.
Error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:115916:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:130570:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:131067:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:127017:43)
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:126946:30
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:126986:28
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:117254:20
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3365:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3130:43)
    at http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3861:36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize that security rules are not filters.  You can't depend on security rules to modify the set of results of a query.  If any document might not match the constraints of the security rules, the entire query fails.  This means that your query needs to only request documents that are know to pass the rules.

Your rules require that the userID on the document match the user's UID:

```
match /Bestellungen/{bestellungID}{
  allow read, write: if resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
}
```

This means that this query will fail every time, because it's requesting documents that could have any userID:

```
this.ordersCollection = db.collection<Order>("Bestellungen");
```

What you need to do instead is query for only documents for the current user:

```
this.ordersCollection = db.collection<Order>("Bestellungen")
    .where("userID", "==", uid);
```

I'm not familiar with Angular, so the syntax might be off.  But the point is that the query on the client **MUST** match the rules, or it will always be rejected.